# Add an action combo to right click menu on any FILE

Tags: windows, right-click

I want to add a combo of actions to right click menu for any file. Lets say I have files on \fileserver\file.exe; word.doc; text.txt...... I would like to have an option to copy that .exe file to local c:\test folder and then open that word.doc file when I right click on that .exe file.

What option do I have to perform this? Regedit? or third party tools?

I found some third party tools that can modify right click menu, but they can't add new functions into it.

Any idea?

Comment: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1176/how-to-add-menu-items-under-right-click-or-context-menu/

Comment: very useful information, i will try this way. thanks.